# PHP preg_replace_callback not replacing my "matches"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

Why is this returning the original string and not the edited string?

Original String:

```
I cant believe Ed ate [-food-] for breakfast.
```

Replace:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[\-[a-zA-Z0-9_]\-\]/', 'tag_func', $email_body);

function tag_func($matches){
     $matches[0] = 'tacos';
     return $matches[0];
}
```

Outcome Desired String:

```
I cant believe Ed ate tacos for breakfast.
```

This is my warning I'm getting:

```
preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'tag_func', to be a valid callback
```

Comment: I thought it may have to do with my version of php, but I'm running 5.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a `+`, so that it should match multiple characters:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[-[a-z\d_]+-\]/i', 'tag_func', $email_body);
//                                 ^
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/f94VPy

---

If you're running 5.3, you can pass it an anonymous function directly:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\[-[a-z\d_]+-\]/i', function () {
    return 'tacos';
}, $email_body);
```

Here's the demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NGBAIh

Comment: This did not do it for me either. I have added the warning I keep getting. Any clues as to solving this puzzle of mine?

Comment: I straight up copied your demo and it didn't work... This is rather frustrating.

Comment: Great news, this in fact worked! I realized my problem and its the fact that I was calling a public static function. I ended up using array('Class Name', 'GetPlaceholderConverter') and it worked as well!